# Android emulator doesn't start, althought it says that is running

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

I have been working for a year with eclipse, but after I upgraded to the Android SDK Tools v20, the emulator doesn't work (absolutely nothing happens). I have everything installed as always, but when I run the emulator, it doesn't appear anymore (althought just after installing SDK Tools v20 it worked twice).
I have even installed again the SO (Linux Mint), after I tried everything I read here, at curiously, the emulator worked 4 or 5 times. The symptoms are these:

-when I run the app, nothing happens in my laptop, but if I put the mouse over the green triangle for running the app, it says: run (already running)

-I've tried to kill the server with adb but doesn't work

-If I list the devices with adb devices, it doesn list any device, even if eclipse says that is running the emulator

-I've tried two different versions of Eclipse: Juno and Galileo, but it's the same

-I've tried to run an emulator independently, but it doesn't work

-I've created several AVD, with different APIs and characteristics, but nothing happens

Does anybody has any solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Good idea to make :Project ->clean 
 Window ->AVD Manager -> pick your virtual device ->Edit-> Snapshot(make sure is disabled) ->Edit AVD (try again, if still not working , then try to launch the emulator directly from AVD  Manager -> Start).
Once the emulator is starting then you can check back the snapshot option again.

If nothing of that works, then try to uninstall/Install SDK again.